# Why split method in java generating empty element at first but not at last?

Tags: java, regex, split

Here is my java split code

```
  String input="[(92, 9), (10, 8), (10, 7), (38, 12), (50, 18), (100, 4)]";
    String[] pairs=input.split("\\[\\(|\\),\\s+\\(|\\)\\]");
    for (String item:pairs){
        System.out.println(" token : "+item);
    }
```

Here is Console output:

```
 token : 
 token : 92, 9
 token : 10, 8
 token : 10, 7
 token : 38, 12
 token : 50, 18
 token : 100, 4
```

Comment: this regex isn't working for me. Please try: /(\\d+,\\s\\d+)/g

Comment: Above regex works. regex you mentioned also works but output has '[' and '(' brackets.